# can we add referrer in http request using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, csrf, csrf-protection

I am testing CSRF on one website. The website prevents CSRF by checking the referrer field. Now I have created an HTML page which sends the request. How can I add the referrer field to that request using JavaScript or any other method?

Comment: Using the referrer field to prevent CSRF does not actually prevent CSRF.  In fact, if you expect an answer to your own question it should be clear to you that such a mechanism is worthless.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader

Comment: @Pointy Having thought this over, I think the question is simply: *is this secure? if not, how can it be broken?*

Answer (score 1):

A web page *shouldn’t* be able to add a `Referer` header to a request using JavaScript. However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), there are still some problems with relying on the `Referer` header:

- Some proxies automatically strip out the `Referer` header. So it’s not always there.
- A web page “can suppress the `Referer` header by issuing requests from FTP or HTTPS URLs.”
- “[O]ld versions of Flash (before 9.0.18) allow malicious Flash to **generate GET or POST requests with arbitrary HTTP request headers** using CRLF Injection.”